# Display related foreign keys in the parent model in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using PostgreSQL for the DB.

I have two models:

`Project` - can contain N Assets.

`Asset` - has a Foreign Key field that points to a Project. An Asset is related to 1 Project.

I want the user to be able to set the order of the Assets of a Project in the Django Admin in a handy way like ordering a list in the edit Project screen.

The order of the Assets is important in my business logic, but I don't want the user to set the order for each individual Asset (just to improve UX).

Is there a way to show a field in the Project admin screen that lists all the Assets that are related to the project and allows the user to order them as he wishes?

I did not find any solution to this other than adding a new field in the Asset modal to specify the order and handling the logic by myself (which is expected), however, I don't want it to be a field that has to be changed manually in each individual Asset.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming your model structure:

Add a `related_name` in your `Asset` model

`models.py`:

```py
# imports ..
class Project(model.Models):
    # other fields
    
class Asset(model.Models):
    project_linked = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='related_assets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then use that to list and oder projects in the admin project listing page:

`admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
# import the Project model

class Projectadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["related_assets"] # add any other desired fields from the Project model
    ordering = ["any_fields from model"] # replace the field with your preference 


admin.site.register(Project, Projectadmin)
```

Upon specifying ordering list, the admin will have a toggle button on top of specified fields to re-order them.